# An integral related to $|\varphi_\alpha'|$

Tags: complex-analysis

This is an exercise. Given that $\varphi_\alpha(z)=\frac{z-\alpha}{1-\overline{\alpha}z}$, where $\alpha \in U$ and $U$ is the unit disc. How do I show that
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{\pi}\int_U |\varphi_\alpha'| dm=\frac{1-|\alpha|^2}{|\alpha|^2}\log \frac{1}{1-|\alpha|^2},
\end{equation} where $m$ is the Lebesgue measure in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $\alpha \ne 0$ (the result for $\alpha=0$ follows from usual real limit results eg L'Hopital), so $\varphi_{\alpha}'(z)=\frac{1}{\bar \alpha}(-1+\frac{1-|\alpha|^2}{1-\bar \alpha z})$, hence $|\varphi_{\alpha}'(z)|=(1-|\alpha|^2)\frac{1}{|1-\bar \alpha z|^2}$

But $\frac{1}{|1-\bar \alpha z|^2}=\frac{1}{(1-\bar \alpha z)(1-\alpha \bar z)}=(\sum_{m \ge 0}{(\bar \alpha z)^m})(\sum_{k \ge 0}{(\alpha \bar z)^k})$.

Since the convergence is absolute and uniform on the unit disc as $|\alpha| < 1$, we can integrate term by term and using polar coordinates it is clear that the integrals are zero unless $k=m$ when we get $\frac{|\alpha|^{2m}}{m+1}$

Hence:

$\frac{1}{\pi}\int_U |\varphi_\alpha'| dm=(1-|\alpha|^2)\sum_{m \ge 0}\frac{|\alpha|^{2m}}{m+1}=\frac{1-|\alpha|^2}{|\alpha|^2}\log \frac{1}{1-|\alpha|^2}$ so we are done!

Comment: This is a nice solution. Thanks a lot!

Comment: happy to be of help